# WebAPI project not working with fiddler

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, https, fiddler

I have a C# WebApi project and it takes in requests and then makes request to another service.

I am trying to see the requests that my service is making via fiddler but I am unable to see the requests.

Heres my webconfig snippet

```html
<log4net>
  ... ... ...
  <root>
    <level value="WARN" />
    <!-- TODO: should the default level be DEBUG ?-->
    <appender-ref ref="EventLogAppender" />
  </root>
</log4net>

<system.net>
  <defaultProxy>
    <proxy bypassonlocal="False" usesystemdefault="True" proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" />
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
... ... ... ...
```

In Fiddler I have 
the following settings set

https section

- https CONNECTs
- Decrypt HTTPS traffic from all processes

Connections

- capture ftp requests
- allow remote computers to connect
- reuse client connections
- reuse server connections
- act as system proxy on startup
- monitor all connections
- default lan
- bypass fiddler that starts with <-lookback>;

Is there anything I am missing????? Or do I have to do something special to get this to work. I receive a cert error in my code and I've tried removing the capture https setting removing the interception cert and shutting down fiddler and then enabling it again ... still doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: `receive a cert error in my code`: What is the EXACT error text? If you run Fiddler and use IE to go to a HTTPS site, do you see any errors?

Comment: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. If i take the webconfig setting out then it works correctly. Im at a loss as to what might be causing this.

Comment: The error message in question would be better worded as: `You have not configured the ASP.NET Service account to trust the Fiddler root certificate.` From the Fiddler book: http://www.ericlawrence.com/eric/images/ul/4-13-15-roottrust.png

Comment: I did this:             ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };